# ionic 2 registerbackbutton function not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic-view

my app.component.ts has this code

```
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar,
    private toastService: ToastService, public app: App) {  
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();

  this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      let view = this.nav.getActive().name;
      console.log('view:', view);
      if (view === "HomeComponent")
        this.platform.exitApp();
      else
        this.toastService.presentToast(new ToastModel("back button pressed"))
  })
});

openPage(page) {
    this.nav.push(page.component);   
}
```

But while pressing back button the app closes although not being on HomeComponent
There are no error on the console and while debugging  on registerBackButton function 
this function is not listed on the platform instance we are using.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `tabs` template or? What shows on debug mode?

Comment: yes . using tab template. no such error on debug mode.
although when i try looking for platform instance . registerBackButton isnt showing as a function.

Comment: On debug mode what is the value for this `let view = this.nav.getActive().name;`?

Comment: @Sampath how to do that on device? i am new to this .Can you tell me how to do this??
emulate?

Comment: You can use this when connected to the USB port. `ionic cordova run android --prod --device`

Comment: you need to do it via android studio right?

Comment: No need.See this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: This too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRAK7h3UDDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152886/discussion-between-manish-kumar-and-sampath).

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

downgrade googlemaps plugin to version: 1.4

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable …

but

Ionic docs have:
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps8… <- this is beta version

the latest version of google breaks that code once downgraded the google maps ,  it got working.